# Inno Setup "Setup Completed" wizard page

Tags: customization, inno-setup

In my installer i support 2 language: English and Italian.

I have a problem with setup complited page where is present a checkbox with label

Run

Also in italian near checkbox teh label report "Run" and not "Avvia" or "Esegui".

I see also inside italian.isl and found this:

---

; *** "Setup Completed" wizard page
FinishedHeadingLabel=Completamento dell'installazione di [name]
FinishedLabelNoIcons=L'installazione di [name] è stata completata con successo.
FinishedLabel=L'installazione di [name] è stata completata con successo. L'applicazione può essere eseguita selezionando le relative icone.
ClickFinish=Premere Fine per uscire dall'installazione.
FinishedRestartLabel=Per completare l'installazione di [name], è necessario riavviare il sistema. Si desidera riavviare adesso?
FinishedRestartMessage=Per completare l'installazione di [name], è necessario riavviare il sistema.%n%nSi desidera riavviare adesso?
ShowReadmeCheck=Si, desidero vedere il file LEGGIMI adesso
YesRadio=&Si, riavvia il sistema adesso
NoRadio=&No, riavvia il sistema più tardi
; used for example as 'Run MyProg.exe'
RunEntryExec=**Avvia** %1
; used for example as 'View Readme.txt'
RunEntryShellExec=**Visualizza** %1

---

All this customization works except RunEntryExec that is showed "run" and not "avvia".
If it is. Else? How i can change "run" word near checkbox in last wizard page?

Bets regards

Comment: It may be displayed from `[CustomMessages] LaunchProgram=Run %1`. Please show us the `[Run]` section from you installer script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RunEntryExec` and `RunEntryShellExec` entries in translation files are used as default captions for the [`postinstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall) check box. And default captions are used when the [`Description`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Description) parameter is empty (or omitted), so your [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section entry contains that text; you have something like:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Description: "Run"; Flags: postinstall
Filename: "{app}\MyDoc.txt"; Description: "Run"; Flags: postinstall shellexec
```

To let the setup use those texts simply remove the [`Description`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Description) parameter:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: postinstall
Filename: "{app}\MyDoc.txt"; Flags: postinstall shellexec
```

Comment: Hi, is correct.
I wrote run section for first by an example... and I forgot. But default translation add also extension to name "Avvia myProgram.exe". So i added in description a CustomMessage with name without ".exe".

thanks!